# Where PHP stores static variables?

Tags: php, mysql, memory, static, memcached

Here is a result of a small test to measure performance between 3 storages: mysql, memcached and php static.

I'm interested in data only during script execution, so static is acceptable.

Steps:

1. filling up storages with 15000 objects (uuid, some name and 1 KB of random data)
2. fetch 5000 uuid keys
3. loop and search each key in 3 storages

Resuts:

```
Object count: 15000
Search requests: 5000
================================
[filling] mysql 
   time: 175.268 s
 memory: 2.519 Mb
================================
[filling] memcached 
   time: 7.79517 s
 memory: 1.9455 Mb
================================
[filling] static 
   time: 0.229687 s
 memory: 3.7875 Mb
================================
[search] mysql 
   time: 3.12171 s
 memory: 0.991821 Mb
================================
[search] memcached 
   time: 1.41455 s
 memory: 0.686646 Mb
================================
[search] static 
   time: 0.0488684 s
 memory: 0.762939 Mb
```

Time and memory are summarized for 5000 search requests.
Measure code

```
$timeInit = (float) microtime(true);
$memoryInit = (float) memory_get_usage(false);
function(); // measured operations
$timeFinish = (float) microtime(true);
$memoryFinish = (float) memory_get_usage(false);
$time = $timeFinish - $timeInit;
$memory = ($memoryFinish - $memoryInit)/1024/1024;
```

So, memcache and mysql store their data outside of php. But where is "static" memory usage?

Could static storage cause lack of memory ("PHP Memory Exhausted Error") during the script?

And what is the best (static or memcache) if I using data only during execution?

Comment: "Where PHP stores static variables?" - Under the side board next to the coffee table!

Comment: Static variables are stored in the heap memory allocated to PHP, so they do take up part of the memory allocation that can lead to "memory exhausted errors": `$object` takes up memory, `self::$data[$object['guid']] = $object;` takes up one array entry of memory, containing a reference to $object

Comment: Note that this would be different if you were storing scalars in your array: you can store any number of pointers to objects, and they are always pointers to the original object instance; if you were assigning scalar variables (integer, float, string, Boolean, or even array) then they actual copies that you store (unless you explicitly set them as references using `&`

Comment: Your comments about copy on change only applies to the passing or arguments to functions

Answer (score -1):

Solved

Seems that the problem is in variable assignment. This code doesn't produce memory allocation for copied variable.

```
$object = [
  'guid' => Guid::generate(),
  'name' => substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7),
  'data' => openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10*1024),
];
// start measure
self::$data[$object['guid']] = $object;
// stop measure
```

But this shows normal memory usage

```
self::$data[$object['guid']] = serialize($object);
```

PHP behavior for this situation explained here

[How PHP manages variables](http://webandphp.com/how-php-manages-variables)

PHP creates a pointer, until we made meanful changes to variable

```
self::$data[$object['guid']] = $object;
self::$data[$object['guid']]['data'] = $object['data']; // reference
self::$data[$object['guid']]['data'] = $object['data'] . ''; // copy
```